# How to use a link label to open a pdf in a web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linklabel

How to use a link label to open a pdf in a web browser ?

I have a Windows Forms application and I am making a REST service request. The response contains the URL of PDF I want to open in a web browser. Is this possible ?

I am referencing this article : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320478

But when I change the url to request a pdf nothing happens.

Here is my code.

```
UrlLink.Text = "http://testurl.com/test.pdf";
               UrlLink.Links.Remove(UrlLink.Links[0]);
               UrlLink.Links.Add(0, UrlLink.Text.Length,
               "http://testurl.com/test.pdf");
```

And the link label event handler:

```
private void UrlLink_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(e.Link.LinkData.ToString());
    Process.Start(sInfo);
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the extra speech marks that are around the URL? (i.e. UrlLink.Text = "http://testurl.com/test.pdf";
               UrlLink.Links.Remove(UrlLink.Links[0]);
               UrlLink.Links.Add(0, UrlLink.Text.Length,
               "http://testurl.com/test.pdf");` Put a breakpoint on `e.Link.LinkData` and check the value of it.

Comment: the double quotes were from poor copy paste skills

Comment: What's the value of 'LinkData' in the LinkClicked event?

Answer (score 0):

If removing the extra speech marks doesn't work, you could try adding the link to the `Description`:

```
UrlLink.Links[0].Description = "http://testurl.com/test.pdf";
```

then

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(e.Link.Description);
```

Comment: I think this adds the linkdata `UrlLink.Links.Add(....` , atleast [MSDN says so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk796z28.aspx)

Comment: Ah yes, it seems like that it that's the case. It might just be a case of OP putting too many speech marks around his URL.